# Algorithm to generate random points inside a circle which has a square inscribed in it not working as it should

Tags: matlab, probability

I try to determine the probabilty of point being inside a square that is inscribed into a circle of radius 1. Firstly I generate my N random points inside my circle and then I check for each one if both the Ox and Oy coordinates are smaller than half of the width respectively the height.I know that the answer gets closer to 2/Pi but I get a number closer to 0,78.. which is not good.

```
`close all;clear all;clc;
%length of width and height
a=sqrt(2);
%radius of circle (it is 1)
raza=a*sqrt(2)/2; 
%total number of points
N=1000;

%Here I generate my N random numbers inside the circle
theta = 2*pi*rand(1,N);
r = rand(1,N);
x = r.*cos(theta);
y = r.*sin(theta);

%here I count how many point are inside the square that is inscribed in the 
%circle
cont = 0;
for i=1:N
    if x(i) >= -a/2 && x(i) <= a/2 && y(i) >= -a/2 && y(i) <= a/2
        cont = cont + 1; 
    end
end
%Here i get sth closer to 0,78...not 2/Pi(0,63..)
cont/N
```

Do I generate the points in a wrong way or do I count the points inside the square improperly?

`

Comment: Your random points are not distributed uniformly. They will be denser toward the center of the circle.

Comment: Thank you! That is the problem.After I modified the radius to be calculated in this way: r = sqrt(rand(1,N)) it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I see there is a simple mistake, please see following formula

```
square_area/circle_area = number_of_total/number_of_inside_circle
```

so

```
(2*R)^2/(pi*R^2) = n_total/n_Indide  --> 4*R^2/pi*R^2=n/cont --> 4/pi = n/con
```

so if you calculate the `cont/N` so you try to calculate `pi/4` base on above formula and 'pi/4`is equal to`0.7854` so your close

NOTE: if you want to calculate `pi` then you can write `4*cont/N`

But if you want to summarize your program you can write it like below

```
n=2000;
x=2*rand(1,n)-1;
y=2*rand(1,n)-1;
inside_index = find(sqrt(x.^2+y.^2)<1); % find index of those point that are inside the circle
PI = 4*numel(inside_index)/n
```

which gave you

```
PI =

  3.1540
```